# How to get exact date in lxml parsing?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I've a weired problem when parsing a html document. The html document has a span something like this:

```
<span class="time">Thu May 17, 2012 12:20 pm</span>
```

When I parse it (it's inside a td) :

```
row.xpath('string(./td/span/text())')
```

I get the following:

```
Wed May 16, 2012 11:20 pm
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, `./td/span` matches multiple elements. When you take the `string()` in the XPath, only the first result gets processed:

```
>>> html = """<html>
...             <td><span class="time">Wed May 16, 2012 11:20 pm</span></td>
...             <td><span class="time">Thu May 17, 2012 12:20 pm</span></td>
...           </html>"""
>>> t = etree.fromstring(html)
>>> t.xpath('string(./td/span)')
'Wed May 16, 2012 11:20 pm'
```

You should write a more specific XPath to get to the row you want, or loop over the rows:

```
>>> for row in t.xpath("./td/span"):
...     print(row.xpath("string(.)"))
...     
Wed May 16, 2012 11:20 pm
Thu May 17, 2012 12:20 pm
```

(Note: I've removed the `text()`, since that's not needed in this case. `text()` [might not do what you think it does](http://community.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell).)

Comment: Yes, I'm looping over the rows and I'm also checking if the row is the same

Comment: I even tried it on python prompt like this: rows[3].xpath('./td/span/text()') but still shows previous date

Comment: @wasimbhalli: then you may have used the wrong XPath expr to get to the rows. How many items does `rows[3].xpath("./td/span")` return?

Comment: It says [<Element span at 0x99cea54>]

Comment: I've used etree.HTML instead of etree.fromstring

Comment: and I get rows like this: rows = doc.xpath("//table[@class='section-block2']/tbody/tr")

Comment: @wasimbhalli: that seems like the right way to get a row (`<tr>`), but within a row you probably have multiple entries (`<td>`).

Comment: yes, I do have multiple tds but I can't find this string in whole html. One interesting thing: all the dates, when parsed, 13 hours are being subtracted from them :|